# Swift best practice: How to keep track of different objects?

Tags: swift, code-structure

I'm wondering what is a good solution to keep track of different objects of same type.

**I have this function:**

```
private extension MenuButtonsViewController {
  // TODO: Find a way to find correct button based on MenuItem
  func buttonFor(for menuItem: MenuItem) -> EmojiButton? {
    guard let subViews = stackView.subviews as? [EmojiButton] else {
      return nil
    }
    let button = buttonFactory.makeEmojiButton(title: menuItem.icon)
    for subView in subViews where subView == button {
      return subView
    }
    return nil
  }
}
```

I have an array (`UIStackView`) with a varying number of buttons (`EmojiButton`). The buttons are created with content from `MenuItem`. 
I'm looking for a good and clean solution how to find and remove a particular button from the `stackView` array, based on a `MenuItem`.

**So far I had three ideas:**

- To create a new object, initalized with same values as the one to remove, and then match using `==`. (Solution above). This didn't work.
- To add an `id` to all buttons, and then a corresponding `id` to the `MenuItem` object. But this doesn't seem like an elegant solution to have to add that everywhere, and expose this variable from the button object.
- Maybe store the button in a wrapper class (like `MenuItemButton`) with an `id` to match to, or by storing the `MenuItem` object so I can match against that.

**Any ideas? How is this usually done?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `MenuItem` and `EmojiButton` inherit from `UIView`, you can make use of the `tag` property that is available on all `UIView`'s.

You first need to assign a unique `tag` value to each of your `MenuItem`'s.

You then need to assign this same value to the corresponding Emoji button's `tag` property. (This would be a good thing to do in your factory.)

Having done that, you can modify your function as follows:

```
//assumes MenuItem and EmojiButton inherit from UIView
func buttonFor(for menuItem: MenuItem) -> EmojiButton? {
    return stackView.viewWithTag(menuItem.tag) as? EmojiButton
}
```